# How to change user without closing applications running?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard

How to change user without closing applications running, on Leopard and Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Preferences under Accounts > "Login Options" you can enable fast user switching by selecting the "Show fast user switching menu as: [Icon, Name, Short name]". After that you should see an user menu on the menubar. Just select "Login window" and you'll be able to login as another user without logging out.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for [command-line based enabling of switching](https://superuser.com/questions/150100/how-to-allow-fast-user-switching-on-a-remote-mac) is also quite relevant. Posting here as a cross-reference.