# How to allow fast user switching on a remote Mac?

Tags: macos, ssh, authentication, remote-access, osx-server

Our server has been locked by a person who haven't logged out after working on it, so now I cannot access it without restart. Can I somehow allow via SSH fast user switching without restarting the system? It's running Snow Leopard.

Comment: I have changed the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To turn on Fast User Switching from the command line:

```
defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences MultipleSessionEnabled -bool YES
```

Change to NO to turn it off.

To trigger Fast User Switching from the command line (if necessary):

```
#Login Window
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend

#Specific User
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -switchToUserID UID_OR_SHORT_USERNAME_HERE
```

Comment: This does nothing for me.  Fast user switching is on.  The CGSession command produces no output (no error message, no prompt for password, nothing) and does nothing - user is not switched.  As a note, I'm trying to do this remotely over SSH if that makes any difference.

Comment: The `CGSession` command doesn't work with short names. It works with user IDs however. Lookup a user's ID via their short name with `id -u usershortname` (should be 501, 502, 503, etc). Then use that in the `CGSession` command.

Answer (score 1):

OSX is Unix so you can ssh into it even if someone is logged in - if you have have set in System Preferences->Sharing->Remote Login

If that is not set then you will need to login as admin sitting at the mac to change that - as there is user switching you don't need to log the other person out

Comment: Yeah, that's what I can do. But I also want to log in directly to this computer (not remotely)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "access"? Access via VNC or Apple Remote Desktop? Do you want to open multiple VNC Sessions?

AFAIK that's not possible.

edit:
I found this: http://www.testplant.com/multidesktop.html
I hope it helps. It doesn't seem to be very comfortable nor for free.

Comment: would the down-voter please comment on the vote?

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but generally speaking, requests for more information should be added as comments, rather than answers.

Comment: It's correct that the first paragraph is a request for more info. But after that you can find my answer. Two answers to be exact. First my "not possible" and then the app i found after googling for a few minutes.

Comment: I meant not remote access, but the direct one. Sorry if I call it wrongly, no idea how to say "logging in by using the keyboard of that computer" in one word