# How to enable fast user switching in Mac OS X 10.6.4

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, fast-user-switching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change user without closing applications running?](https://superuser.com/questions/76388/)

When I go into System Preferences->Accounts I don't see anything that says "Enable Fast User Switching."

Comment: Duplicate of [Leopard: How to change user without closing applications running?](http://superuser.com/questions/76388/leopard-how-to-change-user-without-closing-applications-running) - the steps are identical in Leopard and Snow Leopard.

Comment: That other question is tagged for Leopard 10.6.3, not 10.6.4, but it does answer the question. What's the protocol here? Perhaps we take this to meta.

Comment: I opened discussion in meta http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1325/editing-and-retagging-to-make-a-duplicate-fit